# is "of course" a kind of preposition or fully adverb?

Tags: grammar

We all know there many kinds of preposition in english grammar such as:
Simple,
Double,
Compound,
phrase,
participle,

is "of course" a preposition or adverb?

Answer (score 1):

*Of course* functions as a *sentence adverb* in most cases:

> *Of course* I can help you with that.

Here's how Oxford Dictionaries [defines the term](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/of+course):

> **Sentence adverb**
>   Some adverbs refer to a whole statement and not just a part of it. They are called **sentence adverbs** and they act as a comment, showing the attitude or opinion of the speaker or writer to a particular situation.

See also: [EL&U answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/28441/2303)